# Can a space $Y$ be homotopically equivalent to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to solve an exercise I first read the text wrong. I would like to understand if the following holds.

Let us define $X=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ and let $S=(0,0,-1)$, $N=(0,0,1)$ and finally $Z=\{S,N\}$. Define $Y=X/Z$, i.e. $Y$ is the space $X$ where the two points are identified.

Can we conclude that $Y$ is homotopically equivalent to $S^1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$?

I do not know how to start to get the answer.

Comment: No. The second homology group $H_2(Y)$ is not zero.

Comment: Its $\pi_1$ is also $0$

Comment: I will edit the question.

Comment: @Gae.S. : oh right, my bad.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I do not know homology groups. Can you solve the question without using it?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I was drawing pictures for a few minutes, but I cannot see how to retract the loop obtained by the quotient of a meridian line from $S$ to $N$. Could you please explain to me?

Comment: @DIdier_ : as Gae.S pointed out, I read too quickly, cause the original title had an $X$ in it, not a $Y$. $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge $S^2\vee S^1$, so it has a nonzero $\pi_1$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Oh right, thanks. I was having a headache trying to understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space you're describing is the two-dimensional sphere $S^2$ with its north and south poles identified. As Maxime Ramzi points out in a comment this is *not* homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, in fact it is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$.

You can give $Y$ a cell structure with one $0$-, $1$- and $2$-cell each: use the $0$- and $1$-cell to make a circle, say $\alpha$, and then attach the $2$-cell as follows: glue half the boundary of the disk to one "side" of $\alpha$ and glue the other half to the other "side" (try drawing pictures to see this). But in reality there are no "sides" of a circle, and we're actually just attaching the boundary of the disk to $\alpha \cdot \alpha^{-1}$, which is null-homotopic. It follows that $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to attaching the $2$-cell with a *constant* map (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608908/prove-homotopic-attaching-maps-give-homotopy-equivalent-spaces-by-attaching-a-ce)), which just results in $S^1 \vee S^2$.

Alternatively, if you're allowed to use homology it's straightforward to see that $H_2(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (use the long exact sequence of a pair and the fact that $H_*(X, A) \cong \tilde{H}_*(X/A)$ for "good pairs") so it cannot be homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ since homology is a homotopy-invariant.

---

**Edit:** Jason DeVito made a good point in the comments: since I'm not allowed to use homology, I haven't actually adequately demonstrated that $S^2\vee S^1$ is NOT homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. The first non-homology alternative I can think of is to show $\pi_2(S^2\vee S^1)$ is non-trivial, but that's not exactly elementary (and as Jason also points out the typical way to show $\pi_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is to use Hurewicz and homology). My other idea is with mapping into Eilenberg-MacLane spaces (which is secretly cohomology but you don't have to think about it that way), and hopefully that is basic enough:

Let $K \simeq K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$ be an Eilenberg-MacLane space of type $(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$, i.e. a pointed topological space whose homotopy groups are given by $\pi_i(K) = \mathbb{Z}$ if $i=2$ and $0$ otherwise (fact: these exist and are unique up to homotopy). Then if $[-,-]$ denotes pointed homotopy classes of continuous functions, and $X, Y, Z$ are pointed spaces, then 1) a pointed homotopy equivalence $h\colon X \to Y$ induces a bijection $h^*\colon [Y, Z]\cong [X, Z]$, and 2) it follows from the formal properties of the wedge product that

$$[X\vee Y, Z] \cong [X, Z] \times [Y, Z]. $$

Now observe that $[S^1, K] \cong \pi_1(K) = 0$ and

$$[S^2\vee S^1, K] \cong [S^2, K]\times [S^1, K] \cong [S^2, K]\cong \pi_2(K) \cong \mathbb{Z}. $$

So in particular there is no *pointed* homotopy equivalence between $S^1$ and $S^2\vee S^1$ (I'm not sure if that's enough, but it should be because they are well-pointed spaces).

Comment: Yes, but notice that OP said that he doesn't know much about the homology groups, so he is looking for an answer without using it. But anyway, this is really concise and clear. +1...

Comment: Oh good point. I will try to work out what Maxime said and argue instead that $Y\simeq S^2 \vee S^1$

Comment: As @Kevin.S wrote I was searching for an answer without homology theory. Thank you so much for the answer the same.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini I edited my question to include a non-homology argument

Comment: I am confused.  This answer (correctly) shows that $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$.  The OP asks if $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.  Without a proof that $S^2\vee S^1$ and $S^1$ have different homotopy types, it's not clear to me that this answers the question.  And given that we are not supposed to use  homology (so, likely can't use higher homotopy groups either), it's not clear to me how to convince the OP that $S^2\vee S^1$ and $S^1$ have different homotopy types.

Comment: That is a good point, in that respect my answer isn't complete yet. I personally don't know an easy way of showing they are not homotopy equivalent, other than using homology.

Comment: I don't either.  Anyway, it seems to have satisfies the OP, so perhaps I shouldn't gripe!  +1 from me.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Please take a look at my edit and let me know if that seems like a reasonable/correct explanation.

Comment: The argument is fine, but it's not clear to me that some one with aversion to homology would be happy with your answer (specifically, typically, homology is introduced before higher homotopy groups.  And the proof I have in my head for establishing $\pi_2(S^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is basically the Hurewicz theorem together with knowledge of $H_2(S^2)$).